# How to pass data from json and show in listview

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Hello i have a vuesion pwa template (https://github.com/vuesion/vuesion)

I want to pass data from axios.result to another .vue and show it in a listview.

i found this code:

```
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
        <ListView for="item in listOfItems" class="list-group">
            <v-template>
                <!-- Shows the list item label in the default color and style. -->
                <Label :text="item.nama_event" class="list-group-item" />
            </v-template>
        </ListView>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    const axios = require("axios");

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                listOfItems: []
            };
        },
        mounted: function() {
            axios
                .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
                .then(response => {
                    this.listOfItems = response.data;
                });
        }
    };
</script>
```

and now my Code:

**in App.vue template:**

```
<vue-button slot="right" v-if="isAuthenticated === false" color="primary" @click="getJson">
        Login
</vue-button>

<vue-modal :show="showLoginModal" @close="showLoginModal = false">
      <login-form :loading="isLoginPending" :myObject="info" @submit="onLoginSubmit">
      </login-form>
    </vue-modal>
```

**in App.vue script:**

```
data(): any {
    return {
      isNavigating: false,
      languages: [
        { label: 'English', value: 'en' },
        { label: 'Deutsch', value: 'de' },
        { label: 'Português', value: 'pt' },
        { label: '中文', value: 'zh-cn' },
      ],
      showLoginModal: false,
      isLoginPending: false,
      info: [],
      test1: 'null',
      test2: 'null',
    };


     getJson(){
      axios
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => {
            this.info = response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
      .finally(() => this.showLoginModal = true)
    },
  },
```

and i pass the data to this **LogInForm.vue:**
**script:**

```
export default {
  $_veeValidate: {
    validator: 'new' as 'new',
  },
  name: 'LoginForm',
  components: { VueButton, VueInput, VueHeadline },
  props: {
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
     myObject: {
      type: Array,
    },
  },
  data(): any {
    return {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };
  },
```

**template:**

```
 <ListView for="item in myObject" class="list-group">
            <v-template>
                <!-- Shows the list item label in the default color and style. -->
                <Label :text="item.nama_event" class="list-group-item" />
            </v-template>
        </ListView>
```

i always get this: **error: {"message":"Unable to get property 'nama_event' of undefined or null reference",**

where i'm wrong?

Thanks for your help!!

Edit i changed the url and test a single response.

```
 <!-- Prop: myText -->
<h1><span style="color: #3366ff;"><em>{{ myObject[0].userId }}</em></span></h1>
```

here i got a result!
[image]

edited like that and works now:

```
 <ListView v-for="item in myObject" :key="item">
    <v-template>
      <h2>{{ item.userId }}</h2>
    </v-template>
 </ListView>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `v-for` instead of `for` (in both templates)?

Comment: yeah thanks that was it!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, because it was just a typo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned should be `v-for` in addition you could console.log the results and see exactly what you are receiving.

Comment: yeah thank you !! where and how should i put console.log?

Comment: try this: `.then(response => {
            this.info = response.data;
           console.log(this.info);
      })`